# Stopping my controlled object going off the screen in pygame

Tags: pygame, border

i have started making a game in pygame using python 3.2.2
i have a title screen that has a new game button that when pressed a space background appears with a UFO you can control with the arrow keys
but my UFO can go off the screen in every direction,i want to make it stop on the border of the screen. and i want it to do this on every future screen that will appear later in the game.

i have no idea of the principles to do this...and where it should sit in the code. i read something about rectangles. do i need to define a rectangle then get the ufo to detect this rectangle and stop when it detects the rectangle

any help appreciated

im pretty good at working stuff out,so a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is collision detection. Here is some sample AABB collision detection code in python:

```
def collide(A_top, A_bot, A_left, A_right, B_top, B_bot, B_left, B_right):
    if B_left < A_right and B_top < A_bot and B_right > A_left and B_bot > A_top:
        return True #IS colliding
    return False #IS NOT colliding
```

Now just collide with the borders of the screen, or anything else that happens to be on the screen.

OTHER SOLUTION:

Just check like this:

```
if ufo.x < 0 or ufo.y < 0 or ufo.x + ufo.width > screen.width or ufo.y + ufo.height > screen.height:
    #Do collide code
```